# WP7/8 is it possible to turn on Flash Light with PhotoCamera

Tags: windows-phone-7, light, led

I have a Photo App with Flashmode support so i can decide to use autoFlash, no Flash or flash by every picture which is taken. But no i want to implement that the flash lights the scene to get a good view on QR-Codes for example. 
So the user has to click on the flashmode button to switch the modes: Flashmode.Auto, FlashMode.On, FlashMode.Off and the new one "use Flash LED as a torch" ...
Is this possible in Windows Phone 7 / 8 ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8 you can do it natively, with AudioVideoCaptureDevice and the property VideoTorchMode=On.

On Windows Phone 7 you need to use Reflection and load "Microsoft.Phone.Media.Extended" library to get something like AudioVideoCaptureDevice and turn on the flash while you'r recording a video.

That could be useful for use the flashlight in WP7.
http://www.locked.nl/wp7-flashlight-getting-started

Comment: Thx, i found the tutorial before, but i need a photocamera to take a snapshot and not a video and this doesn't work together (but it is also possible that i am a newbee and don't understand how to combine this)

Comment: PS: in his tutorial he said "It seems that using the photo camera to build a flashlight is not going to work." but i wont believe this so easy... :)

Answer (score 0):

in xaml:

```
  <VideoBrush x:Name="PART_VideoBrush">
                            <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="PART_VideoTransform" CenterX=".5"CenterY=".5"  />
                            </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        </VideoBrush>
```

in your code behind:

```
 PhotoCamera _cam = new PhotoCamera();
    this._cam.Initialized += _cam_Initialized;
  CameraVideoBrushExtensions.SetSource(this.PART_VideoBrush, this._cam);
                this.PART_VideoTransform.Rotation = 90.0;


 private void _cam_Initialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;           //FrashMode.ON,Auto, RedEyeReduction
        }
```

Comment: mhh... to see something in my preview i have to do `PART_VideoBrush.SetSource(_photoCamera);`
but if i do so the `CameraVideoBrushExtensions.SetSource(this.PART_VideoBrush, this._cam);` Throws a 

`{System.InvalidOperationException: Already initialized. .SetSource can only be called once on camera instance.
   at Microsoft.Devices.Camera.InitializeVideoSession(VideoBrush brush)
   at Microsoft.Devices.CameraVideoBrushExtensions.SetSource(VideoBrush brush, Camera camera)
   at deepView.MainPage.OnPhotoCameraInitialized(Object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)}`

exception...

Comment: If i delete the line `PART_VideoBrush.SetSource(_photoCamera);` no preview is available and the flash led doesn't light up the scene continuosly (FlashMode.on)...